# Drupal Commons change theme

Tags: theming, users, 7

I'm pretty new to Drupal, I installed Drupal Commons in order to build a website where users can register and create a custom profile. Users will be split in categories.

I'm not entirely sure Drupal Commons is the best choice for me.

Anyways, now I find myself in the following situation:
- I cannot find a way to change the Commons Origins default theme, let alone find a place where I can acquire such themes.

Answer (score 3):

You can essentially download and upload a new theme to your site by following the instructions here:

https://drupal.org/getting-started/install-contrib/themes

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is download a theme from http://drupal.org/project/themes

Extract your theme in your site/all/themes folder

Go to administer -> site building -> themes and enable the theme(make sure to set it as the default theme), save it and you should have your new theme enabled.